# How to debug the CPU tab on Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi 11. Sometimes an exception happens, and instead of Delphi going to the unit that threw the exception, it goes to this CPU screen, and I don't know what to do with it.

What can I do in such situations ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of screen typically means there is no code located at the memory address where the CPU tried to execute code from. Which most likely means that a class method was called on an object via an invalid but not nil pointer, or a function was called via a similarly invalid function pointer.

You won't be able to debug the location where the exception was raised from, since it is an invalid memory address to begin with. But you should still have access to the [Call Stack](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Call_Stack_Window) trace of function calls that led up to the exception. So, just walk back through the Call Stack until you reenter valid code, and then debug from there to find the invalid pointer.

Comment: Thank you , but sorry for the ignorance, how can i 'walk back' on this CPU screen ? I only know how to go forward hitting F7 / F8

Comment: I did not say to 'walk back' in the CPU screen.  I said to do that from the Call Stack instead. There is a [separate debugger window](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Call_Stack_Window) for that.

Comment: My Delphi 11 does too even in `_Float := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);`. I didn't use Delphi for some years and I just downloaded the newest trial version. Something changed?

Comment: @SHINJaeGuk I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: When I input strings in the Edit Delphi 11 doesn't break on the code which fires EConvertError exection but opens CPU debug window like OP's case.

Comment: I have just installed Delphi 10.4 Community and it breaks on System.SysUtils.ConverErrorFmt. If there were many StrToFloat methods how can I find it?

Comment: @SHINJaeGuk it breaks on the code that actually `raise`'s the exception. `StrToFloat()` calls `ConvertErrorFmt()` on failure. As I explained in my answer, simply go to the Call Stack window and walk the list to find the code that is calling `StrToFloat()` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

There might be better answers but I think you might look at [EurekaLog](https://www.eurekalog.com/index_delphi.php) or [madExcept](https://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm). Either works great.  Never quite understood why this is not built-in to Delphi.